# Getting symmetry of a function graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions, symmetry

Consider we have an function $f(x)$ and it has a inverse relation and consider that function starts from a point somewhere else in $+x$ axis. When we want to draw its $f^{-1}(x)$ (inverse function) we are making his symmetry based on $x=y$ because its changes its domain set and $(x)$ codomain $(y)$ so, when we want to get a symmetry of $+x$ its being $+y$ because we get its symmetry based on $x=y$.

Is every function manipulation based on making symmetry work likes this, and is this true to think like this?

Comment: Yes it always work when the function is invertible.

Comment: Refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2237909/505767

Comment: But i am also asking for other symmetries. Like are there more like this one, and do we make the same thing for all of them?

Comment: Yes for example making $+x \to -x$ for $y=x^2$ or $+y \to -y$ for $y=x^2$ and $y=-x^2$, and so on.