Numerical Inverse of an integral
Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty)$ be a continuous function. Define $F: \mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty)$ by:
\begin{equation*}
F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt
\end{equation*}
Clearly, $F$ is strictly increasing and differentiable.
Is there any general algorithms for numerically invert $F$?
That is, given $y \in \mathbb{R}$, guaranteed to be inside the range of $F$, how to numerically approximate $F^{-1}(y)$? We assume here that $f$ is known but of very complicated form such that the only computation feasible is to evaluate $f$ at a given $t \in \mathbb{R}$. (In particular, it is preferred not to carry out numerical integration more than several times...)

One may solve the differential equation $(F^{−1})'(a)=\dfrac{1}{f(F^{-1}(a))}$

How does this work? Computation of $f'$ would be impossible.

You don't need $f'$ but just $F'$ which is $f$, treat $y=F^{-1}$ as the unknown function. In others words : $g^{-1}(a)=\dfrac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(a))}$ with $g=F$.

Followed by numerically estimate the solution? It seems to be a good idea. Let me think about it.

Yes with a numerical approach and estimation it could be good, let me know your results.

Since $F$ is monotonic, the inverse at a given point can be easily found by a bisection method or something similar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method

I am not sure about bisection method. Please elaborate. Note that I really do not want to evaluate $F(x)$ for too many times.

You may also consider the symetric graph for graphical approach : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2237909/are-the-graphs-of-inverse-functions-always-reflections-of-the-functions-graph-i

Bisection or Newton's Method could be appropriate. Newton may not converge if the initial guess is to far though

Have a look at the sophistication that goes into quality approximations of, for example, the inverse error function. An older paper worth reading.
